# Voting to close in the "First Posts" review queue improperly updates the close link's text

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close, design

I just found another bug that relates to close votes.

I was reviewing First Posts on main SO, and voted to close one. Afterwards, the bar of actions below the post changed to this:

```
...| close Your vote has been recorded |...
```

<sub><sup>Little dots mine. The other actions were still there.</sup></sub>

Why can't we just have `close (1)`? I'm lazy, but I can still count between 0 and 5.

Also, can we have our pretty little blue box back?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @JarrodDixon Does it seem to be isolated to the review queues?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug in the "First Posts" queue; working on it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript for that "First Posts" queue had an issue - a fix has been deployed to all sites.

Thanks for finding it!

Comment: You're welcome! I could be a full-time stuff breaker for Stack Exchange.